# AngularJS cookie with array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I send my data like this

`$cookies.putObject("currentLocation,values,allLocList", obj, vm.tempData, vm.allLocationList);` obj and `vm.tempData` are `objects`. But `vm.allLocationList` is array that contains a JSON object.

In my state file, I get data with

```
  resolve: {
  entity: function($cookies) {
    return {
      location: $cookies.getObject("currentLocation"),
      values: $cookies.getObject("values"),
      allLocationList: $cookies.getObject("allLocList")
    };
  }
}
```

Then when i go to controller, `entity.location` is okey,`entity.values` is okey but `entity.allLocList` is undefined.Do you have any idea?

Comment: `putObject(key, value, [options]);` - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Comment: Array is not possible.Am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `$cookies.putObject(key, value, [options]);` - [$cookies documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies):

#### Set your values one by one (key, value):

```
$cookies.putObject("currentLocation",obj);
$cookies.putObject("values", vm.tempData);
$cookies.putObject("allLocList", vm.allLocationLis);
```

---

### Get your values

```
resolve: {
  entity: function($cookies) {
    return {
      location: $cookies.getObject("currentLocation"),
      values: $cookies.getObject("values"),
      allLocationList: $cookies.getObject("allLocList")
    };
  }
}
```

**> [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzh1f4zq/)**